# $ sudo service mysql restart Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, server

I was trying to do this:
Install MariaDB

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-10.3

$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Edit the file "/etc/mysql/my.cnf"

```
$ sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And add the following content:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Run MariaDB server:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

but caught up with this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-177:~$ sudo service mysql restart
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```